# Past Perfect usage

Tags: past-perfect, figures-of-speech, books

I'm reading a book and found this odd usage of past perfect tense in a speech of a character: *"He never feels as if he knows, neither does he feel as if nothing **had happened**"*. My English teacher (not a native speaker) told me that it's grammatically incorrect and it's just a speaking style of the character. Is it a correct conclusion? Or maybe there's a hidden sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is the book you are reading;
[Tales of Power](https://books.google.co.jp/books?id=4ECtQBF3NZEC&pg=PA52&lpg=PA52&dq=He%20never%20feels%20as%20if%20he%20knows,%20neither%20does%20he%20feel%20as%20if%20nothing%20had%20happened&source=bl&ots=uPs_vh3TWP&sig=cWtr3ACApOYQoGIyRUAVZ60bCaU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiQp83w9f3KAhUCUZQKHZqjDnkQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=He%20never%20feels%20as%20if%20he%20knows%2C%20neither%20does%20he%20feel%20as%20if%20nothing%20had%20happened&f=false)

That sentence is not common for sure but I wouldn't say it is grammatically wrong. Your grammar book is right. However, there is more to your sentence. There is more context. Look at the previous sentences.

With past perfect tense, there needs to be a **said** or **imagined** other past event that was later than in your sentence.

I read that whole page and interpret the part with "warrior's way" like this:
Many things happen. The warrior doesn't believe, but accepts everything. He accepted those things like nothing had happened (although before he accepted, there are things that had happened).

The most common usage you will find is "He acts as if nothing has happened".

Ps. Being a native doesn't make one automatically a perfect teacher (grammar wise).

Answer (score 1):

It's an unusual sequencing of tenses. The quotation comes from Carlos Casteneda, part of an extensive narrative of shamanist mysticism - hardly an ideal text for exploring English grammar in any case, but certainly a context in which one might *expect* the verb tenses to be odd.

More context might help, of course, and my copy of *Tales of Power* is nowhere at hand.  In general, though, I would trust Casteneda's rendering as intentional, and not be too quick to dismiss it as an error, either by the speaker or by the author.